# Формирование данных с формы для отправки через AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form

Есть форма

```
<form id="upload-docs" name="uploadDocs">
  <div class="field-upload">
    <label for="file1">Файл1:</label>
    <input id="file1" name="file1" type="file" accept=".xlsx,.xls,image/*,.doc, .docx,.ppt, .pptx,.txt,.pdf">
  </div>
  <div class="field-upload">
    <label for="file2">Файл 2:</label>
    <input id="file2" name="file2" type="file" accept=".xlsx,.xls,image/*,.doc, .docx,.ppt, .pptx,.txt,.pdf">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Загрузить файлы">
</form>
```

Пытаюсь собрать данные так

```
$('#upload-docs').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  let formData = new FormData(document.forms.uploadDocs);
});
```

Но переменная `formData` остается пустой. Где я просчитался или может по другому как-то собрать данные с формы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Где я просчитался или может по другому как-то собрать данные с формы?

Вот так собирают, файлы.

```js
$('#upload-docs').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData();
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Вот так файлы ловят
  formData.append("file1", $('#file1').prop('files')[0]);
  formData.append("file2", $('#file2').prop('files')[0]);
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  
  // Debbug output
  console.log($('#file2').prop('files')[0],
    $('#file2').prop('files')[0]);
    
  // Распечатка того, что есть в formData
  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.info(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="upload-docs" name="uploadDocs">
  <div class="field-upload">
    <label for="file1">Файл1:</label>
    <input id="file1" name="file1" type="file" accept=".xlsx,.xls,image/*,.doc, .docx,.ppt, .pptx,.txt,.pdf">
  </div>
  <div class="field-upload">
    <label for="file2">Файл 2:</label>
    <input id="file2" name="file2" type="file" accept=".xlsx,.xls,image/*,.doc, .docx,.ppt, .pptx,.txt,.pdf">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Загрузить файлы">
</form>
```

[Док. FormData.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

Comment: почему я не могу в цикле `each` собрать данные? ошибка вываливается. `$('form#upload-docs input').each(function() {
                formData.append(this.name, $(this).prop('files')[0]);
            });`

Comment: @Алексей Это уже другой вопрос, задайте отдельно. К новому вопросу, добавьте код с вашими попытками, опишите, что работает, а что нет. Какого результата, хотели бы добиться.